# Firstore Admin SDK: Dynamic map members in `UpdateData`- is it possible?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can have

```
interface MyInterface {
  // viewCount: { [userId: string]: number };
  downloaded?: { [userId: string]: boolean };
}
export type MyInterfaceUpdate = admin.firestore.UpdateData<MyInterface>;

export function a() {
  let a = "asdf"
  const update: MyInterfaceUpdate = {
    [`downloaded.${a}`]: true,
    // ['viewCount.testUser']: 23,
  }
}
```

Note: Only one map in the interface

or I can have

```
interface MyInterface {
  viewCount: { [userId: string]: number };
  downloaded?: { [userId: string]: boolean };
}
export type MyInterfaceUpdate = admin.firestore.UpdateData<MyInterface>;

export function a() {
  const update: MyInterfaceUpdate = {
    [`downloaded.asdf`]: true,
    ['viewCount.testUser']: 23,
  }
}
```

Note: No var in the `downloaded.asdf` for the update.

But the combination does not work. Why?

Here the combo:

```
interface MyInterface {
  viewCount: { [userId: string]: number };
  downloaded?: { [userId: string]: boolean };
}
export type MyInterfaceUpdate = admin.firestore.UpdateData<MyInterface>;

export function a() {
  let a = "asdf"
  const update: MyInterfaceUpdate = { // Error here "index sigbatures are incompatible"
    [`downloaded.${a}`]: true,
    ['viewCount.testUser']: 23,
  }
}
```

Note: It does work if `downloaded` and `viewCount` have not different types (both string or boolean e.g.)

Is there a way to make it work?:)

Comment: I'm not clear.  Are you expecting the Firestore update dot notation to match the TypeScript interfaces?  If so, that's not how dot notation works.  It has nothing to do with JavaScript/TypeScript.  It's unique to Firestore so that it can understand how to deeply update nested fields in any programming language.

Comment: The error I have (commented in the code) is a type error that I only get when using both string interpolation in the dot notation AND have two maps of different types in my interface.

I just wonder whether there is a way to avoid the error, as both mentioned causes work individually if not combined..

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do isn't syntactically understood by TypeScript.

Your interface requires data that's structured like this:

```
const data: MyInterface = {
    viewCount: { "uid": 23 },
    downloaded: { "uid": true },
}
```

You can't simulate that using Firestore dot notation syntax or any other string interpolation syntax.  It just doesn't work.  Your update object for a Firestore document to modify just those two fields is never going to match that of your interface as it's currently defined - it's a completely different structure (specifically, just string keys mapped to values, no matter how the string key is being built).